# Violación de segmento ('core' generado) en python

Tags: python, linux

Tengo este código en python, el cual grafica IONEX data (example.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import re
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import wget
import subprocess
import matplotlib.cm
import matplotlib.colors

# Larger figure size
fig_size = [14, 10]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = fig_size

def parse_map(tecmap, exponent = -1):
    tecmap = re.split('.*END OF TEC MAP', tecmap)[0]
    return np.stack([np.fromstring(l, sep=' ') for l in re.split('.*LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H\\n',tecmap)[1:]])*10**exponent

def get_tecmaps(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        ionex = f.read()
        return [parse_map(t) for t in ionex.split('START OF TEC MAP')[1:]]

def get_tec(tecmap, lat, lon):
    i = int(round((87.5 - lat)*(tecmap.shape[0]-1)/(2*87.5)))
    j = int(round((180 + lon)*(tecmap.shape[1]-1)/360))
    return tecmap[i,j]

def ionex_filename(year, day, centre, zipped = True):
    return '{}g{:03d}0.{:02d}i{}'.format(centre, day, year % 100, '.Z' if zipped else '')

def ionex_ftp_path(year, day, centre):
    return 'ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/products/ionex/{:04d}/{:03d}/{}'.format(year, day, ionex_filename(year, day, centre))

def ionex_local_path(year, day, centre = 'esa', directory = '/tmp', zipped = False):
    return directory + '/' + ionex_filename(year, day, centre, zipped)

def download_ionex(year, day, centre = 'esa', output_dir = '/tmp'):
    wget.download(ionex_ftp_path(year, day, centre), output_dir)
    subprocess.call(['gzip', '-d', ionex_local_path(year, day, centre, output_dir, zipped = True)])

def plot_tec_map(tecmap):
    proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj))
    ax.coastlines()
    h = plt.imshow(tecmap, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=100, extent = (-180, 180, -87.5, 87.5), transform=proj)
    plt.title('VTEC map')
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    ax_cb = divider.new_horizontal(size='5%', pad=0.1, axes_class=plt.Axes)
    f.add_axes(ax_cb)
    cb = plt.colorbar(h, cax=ax_cb)
    plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
    cb.set_label('TECU ($10^{16} \\mathrm{el}/\\mathrm{m}^2$)')

for tecmap in get_tecmaps(ionex_local_path(2018, 349)):
    plot_tec_map(tecmap)
    plt.show()
```

Sin embargo, cuando lo ejecuto me sale una pantalla negra y luego esto:

```
fernanda@fernanda-astro:~/gnss/Data$ python example.py 
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
fernanda@fernanda-astro:~/gnss/Data$
```

Lo que deseo es que se execute esta gráfica TEC:
[image: TEC]

Tengo la versión de Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.15 y este es mi pip list:

```
fernanda@fernanda-astro:~/gnss/Data$ pip list
Package                            Version                   Location                 
---------------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------------
aacgmv2                            2.5.0                     
absl-py                            0.5.0                     
alabaster                          0.7.12                    
anaconda-client                    1.7.2                     
anaconda-navigator                 1.9.6                     
anaconda-project                   0.8.2                     
apexpy                             1.0.3                     
asn1crypto                         0.24.0                    
astor                              0.7.1                     
astroid                            1.6.5                     
astropy                            2.0.9                     
atomicwrites                       1.2.1                     
attrs                              18.2.0                    
Babel                              2.6.0                     
backports-abc                      0.5                       
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.5                       
backports.os                       0.1.1                     
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0                     
backports.ssl-match-hostname       3.5.0.1                   
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1                 
basemap                            1.2.0                     
bcrypt                             3.1.4                     
beautifulsoup4                     4.6.3                     
bitarray                           0.8.3                     
bkcharts                           0.2                       
blaze                              0.11.3                    
bleach                             3.0.2                     
bokeh                              1.0.2                     
boto                               2.49.0                    
Bottleneck                         1.2.1                     
Cartopy                            0.17.0                    
cdecimal                           2.3                       
certifi                            2018.11.29                
cffi                               1.11.5                    
cftime                             1.0.3.4                   
chardet                            3.0.4                     
Click                              7.0                       
cliff                              2.13.0                    
cloudpickle                        0.6.1                     
clyent                             1.2.2                     
cmd2                               0.8.9                     
cntk                               2.6                       
colorama                           0.4.1                     
conda                              4.6.7                     
conda-build                        3.17.6                    
conda-verify                       3.1.1                     
configparser                       3.5.0                     
contextlib2                        0.5.5                     
coverage                           4.5.1                     
cryptography                       2.4.2                     
cycler                             0.10.0                    
Cython                             0.29.2                    
cytoolz                            0.9.0.1                   
dask                               1.0.0                     
datashape                          0.5.4                     
debtcollector                      1.20.0                    
decorator                          4.3.0                     
defusedxml                         0.5.0                     
distributed                        1.25.1                    
docutils                           0.14                      
drms                               0.5.5                     
entrypoints                        0.2.3                     
enum34                             1.1.6                     
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1                     
extras                             1.0.0                     
fastcache                          1.0.2                     
fasteners                          0.14.1                    
faulthandler                       3.1                       
filelock                           3.0.10                    
fixtures                           3.0.0                     
Flask                              1.0.2                     
Flask-Cors                         3.0.7                     
funcsigs                           1.0.2                     
functools32                        3.2.3.post2               
future                             0.17.1                    
futures                            3.2.0                     
gast                               0.2.0                     
gevent                             1.3.7                     
glob2                              0.6                       
Glymur                             0.8.15                    
gmpy2                              2.0.8                     
greenlet                           0.4.15                    
grin                               1.2.1                     
grpcio                             1.15.0                    
h5py                               2.8.0                     
heapdict                           1.0.0                     
html5lib                           1.0.1                     
hypothesis                         3.71.3                    
IDLSave                            1.0.0                     
idna                               2.8                       
imageio                            2.4.1                     
imagesize                          1.1.0                     
importlib-metadata                 0.6                       
ipaddress                          1.0.22                    
ipykernel                          4.10.0                    
ipyparallel                        6.2.2                     
ipython                            5.8.0                     
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0                     
ipywidgets                         7.4.2                     
irispy                             0.0.dev368                /home/fernanda/irispy-git
iso8601                            0.1.12                    
isort                              4.3.4                     
itsdangerous                       1.1.0                     
jdcal                              1.4                       
jedi                               0.13.2                    
Jinja2                             2.10                      
jsonschema                         2.6.0                     
jupyter                            1.0.0                     
jupyter-client                     5.2.4                     
jupyter-console                    5.2.0                     
jupyter-core                       4.4.0                     
jupyterlab                         0.33.11                   
jupyterlab-launcher                0.11.2                    
Keras                              2.2.2                     
Keras-Applications                 1.0.4                     
Keras-Preprocessing                1.0.2                     
keyring                            12.2.0                    
kiwisolver                         1.0.1                     
kPyWavelet                         0.0.1                     
lazy-object-proxy                  1.3.1                     
leo                                5.7                       
libarchive-c                       2.8                       
lief                               0.9.0                     
linecache2                         1.0.0                     
llvmlite                           0.26.0                    
locket                             0.2.0                     
Logbook                            1.4.0                     
lxml                               4.2.5                     
madrigalWeb                        3.1.10                    
Markdown                           2.6.11                    
MarkupSafe                         1.1.0                     
matplotlib                         2.2.3                     
mccabe                             0.6.1                     
mistune                            0.8.4                     
mkl-fft                            1.0.6                     
mkl-random                         1.0.2                     
mock                               2.0.0                     
monotonic                          1.5                       
more-itertools                     4.3.0                     
mpmath                             1.1.0                     
msgpack                            0.5.6                     
multipledispatch                   0.6.0                     
MySQL-python                       1.2.5                     
navigator-updater                  0.2.1                     
nbconvert                          5.4.0                     
nbformat                           4.4.0                     
ndcube                             0.1.dev0                  
netaddr                            0.7.19                    
netCDF4                            1.4.2                     
netifaces                          0.10.7                    
networkx                           2.2                       
nltk                               3.4                       
nose                               1.3.7                     
notebook                           5.7.4                     
numba                              0.41.0+0.gf118cda06.dirty 
numexpr                            2.6.8                     
numpy                              1.15.4                    
numpydoc                           0.8.0                     
odo                                0.5.1                     
olefile                            0.46                      
openpyxl                           2.5.12                    
ordereddict                        1.1                       
oslo.concurrency                   3.27.0                    
oslo.config                        6.4.0                     
oslo.context                       2.21.0                    
oslo.i18n                          3.21.0                    
oslo.log                           3.39.0                    
oslo.serialization                 2.27.0                    
oslo.utils                         3.37.0                    
OWSLib                             0.17.1                    
packaging                          18.0                      
pandas                             0.23.4                    
pandocfilters                      1.4.2                     
paramiko                           2.4.2                     
parso                              0.3.1                     
partd                              0.3.9                     
path.py                            11.5.0                    
pathlib                            1.0.1                     
pathlib2                           2.3.3                     
patsy                              0.5.1                     
pbr                                4.2.0                     
pdu                                0.0.3                     
pep8                               1.7.1                     
pexpect                            4.6.0                     
pickleshare                        0.7.5                     
pIDLy                              0.2.7                     
Pillow                             5.3.0                     
pip                                19.0.3                    
pipenv                             11.9.0                    
pkginfo                            1.4.2                     
pluggy                             0.8.0                     
ply                                3.11                      
prettytable                        0.7.2                     
prometheus-client                  0.5.0                     
prompt-toolkit                     1.0.15                    
protobuf                           3.6.1                     
psutil                             5.4.8                     
ptyprocess                         0.6.0                     
pvlib                              0.6.0                     
py                                 1.7.0                     
pyandoc                            0.0.1                     
pyasn1                             0.4.4                     
pycairo                            1.18.0                    
pycodestyle                        2.4.0                     
pycosat                            0.6.3                     
pycparser                          2.19                      
pycrypto                           2.6.1                     
pycurl                             7.43.0.2                  
pyephem                            3.7.6.0                   
pyepsg                             0.4.0                     
pyflakes                           2.0.0                     
Pygments                           2.3.1                     
pyinotify                          0.9.6                     
pykdtree                           1.3.1                     
pylint                             1.9.2                     
PyNaCl                             1.2.1                     
pyodbc                             4.0.25                    
pyOpenSSL                          18.0.0                    
pypandoc                           1.4                       
pyparsing                          2.3.0                     
pyperclip                          1.6.4                     
pyproj                             1.9.6                     
pyrap                              0.0.5                     
pysat                              1.1.0                     
pysatCDF                           0.3.0                     
pysatMagVect                       0.3.1                     
pyshp                              2.1.0                     
PySocks                            1.6.8                     
pytest                             4.0.2                     
pytest-arraydiff                   0.2                       
pytest-astropy                     0.4.0                     
pytest-doctestplus                 0.1.3                     
pytest-mock                        1.10.0                    
pytest-openfiles                   0.3.0                     
pytest-remotedata                  0.3.0                     
python-dateutil                    2.7.5                     
python-mimeparse                   1.6.0                     
python-subunit                     1.3.0                     
pytz                               2018.7                    
PyWavelets                         1.0.1                     
PyYAML                             3.13                      
pyzmq                              17.1.2                    
QtAwesome                          0.5.3                     
qtconsole                          4.4.3                     
QtPy                               1.5.2                     
radiospectra                       0.1.2                     
requests                           2.21.0                    
requests-toolbelt                  0.8.0                     
rfc3986                            1.1.0                     
RMextract                          0.1                       
rope                               0.11.0                    
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.46                   
scandir                            1.9.0                     
scikit-image                       0.14.1                    
scikit-learn                       0.20.1                    
scipy                              1.1.0                     
seaborn                            0.9.0                     
SecretStorage                      2.3.1                     
semantic-version                   2.6.0                     
Send2Trash                         1.5.0                     
setuptools                         40.6.3                    
sgp4                               1.4                       
Shapely                            1.6.4.post2               
simplegeneric                      0.8.1                     
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3                   
siphon                             0.8.0                     
six                                1.12.0                    
snowballstemmer                    1.2.1                     
sortedcollections                  1.0.1                     
sortedcontainers                   2.1.0                     
Sphinx                             1.8.4                     
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.1.0                     
spyder                             3.3.2                     
spyder-kernels                     0.3.0                     
SQLAlchemy                         1.2.15                    
statsmodels                        0.9.0                     
stestr                             2.1.1                     
stevedore                          1.29.0                    
subprocess32                       3.5.3                     
suds-jurko                         0.6                       
sunpy                              0.9.2                     
sympy                              1.3                       
tables                             3.4.4                     
tblib                              1.3.2                     
tempest                            19.0.0                    
tensorboard                        1.10.0                    
tensorflow                         1.10.1                    
termcolor                          1.1.0                     
terminado                          0.8.1                     
testpath                           0.4.2                     
testtools                          2.3.0                     
toolz                              0.9.0                     
tornado                            5.1.1                     
tqdm                               4.28.1                    
traceback2                         1.4.0                     
traitlets                          4.3.2                     
treepick                           0.1.4                     
twine                              1.11.0                    
typing                             3.6.6                     
unicodecsv                         0.14.1                    
unittest2                          1.1.0                     
urllib3                            1.24.1                    
virtualenv                         15.2.0                    
virtualenv-clone                   0.3.0                     
voluptuous                         0.11.5                    
waipy                              0.0.9.0                   
wcwidth                            0.1.7                     
webencodings                       0.5.1                     
Werkzeug                           0.14.1                    
wget                               3.2                       
wheel                              0.32.3                    
widgetsnbextension                 3.4.2                     
wrapt                              1.10.11                   
wurlitzer                          1.0.2                     
xlrd                               1.2.0                     
XlsxWriter                         1.1.2                     
xlwt                               1.3.0                     
yorn                               0.0.6                     
zict                               0.1.3   

Además cuando intento abrir otra terminal me sale esto:

(base) fernanda@fernanda-astro:~/gnss/Data$
```

Podría alguien ayudarme

Le agradezco de antemano

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!